# Not getting correct data with Custom implementation of simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have to make a small change in one of my existing app. It has a listview, which fetches data from a database and displays it using a custom simplecursoradapter.

I need to make some change in the onclick listener on an image shown in the custom listview.

I am not able to get the correct data for the item clicked in the listview.

```
ListItem

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSpeak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>


Cursor temp=mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
String[] from=new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_WORD};
int[] to= new int[]{R.id.tvWord};
words = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.word_list_item, temp, from, to);

public Cursor fetchAllNotes(){
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_WORD}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Cursor temp;

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        temp=cursor;
        temp.moveToFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView ivSpeak=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivSpeak);
        final TextView tvWord=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvWord);

        temp.moveToPosition(position);
        final int pos=position;

        ivSpeak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{

                    Log.d("ambit", temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_WORD))+"word"); // This is not giving the correct word in my dataset
                    Log.d("ambit", pos + "position"); //This is fine
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moveToPosition() your Cursor on your onClickListener :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                temp.moveToPosition(position);
                Log.d("ambit", temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_WORD))+"word"); // This is not giving the correct word in my dataset
                Log.d("ambit", pos + "position"); //This is fine
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```